# facing issue in zombie application

Tags: ios

I am using a zombies application from the instruments where I had connected the real device
to mac and was trying to find the leaks but I am getting "Target fail to run:Permission to debug com.app.view was denied.The app must be signed with a development identity",but I had used the certificates to run the app.

Can any one guide me how to solve this problem

Comment: What "zombies application"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't launch my app in Instruments: At least one target failed to launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905450/cant-launch-my-app-in-instruments-at-least-one-target-failed-to-launch)