# Can debug app on device but cannot profile: the app must be signed with a development identity

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, profiler, provisioning-profile

I have custom schemes such as `DebugStaging` that are signed with a *development* identity.

I use these schemes to run the app on my phone from Xcode on debug. However, any attempt to profile using these schemes results in

`Target failed to run: Permission to debug [app name] was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer)`

What in the heck is going on and how do I rid Xcode of this evil??

Edit: We long ago deleted the `Debug` scheme to use more verbose scheme names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't launch my app in Instruments: At least one target failed to launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905450/cant-launch-my-app-in-instruments-at-least-one-target-failed-to-launch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting derived data worked.

In my case, no `Debug` build configuration existed because it was deleted and I am using completely custom configurations.

Answer (score 26):

Go to the scheme for your target, Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, then select 'Profile' from the left menu and set the Build Configuration to Debug.

Comment: There is no `Debug` option. `DebugStaging` is an option. Interestingly I can profile on our `DebugProduction` scheme with the `DebugProduction` build configuration. I'll try to investigate more into what the difference is here since there must be a deeper underlying reason the profiler works on one but not the other.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I deleted derived data and everything started working :shrug:. You'll have to take my word that no `Debug` option exists since this is a private codebase.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6 and there us Debug option in Profile section.

Comment: Ya, but we removed that option in order to include more verbose options for our schemes.