# ios app-on-device debugging events

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging

Newbie here, so apologies if this is stupid question:

Are there any applications or solutions out there that would allow you access to debugging events on an app installed on your iphone? To be clear, this isn't an app I've developed, it's just on my iphone and is used as part of another solution which we are developing. Curious if there's a way to just watch the events on an app to help with debugging process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an app, and build it with a development release, and development signing, you can select to build+run it on a device. Then, you can use the Xcode debugger to see your logs / errors etc.

Steps:

1. Plug in iPhone
2. Start Xcode
3. Hit Build + run
4. Watch debugger

Logs are either made by the OS for certain things (NSinconsistency, bad constraints, race conditions in view presentation) or by you with NSLog.

Or did you mean when the app is not tethered to your computer? There are other tools for that - including just plugging the phone back in and downloading the logs off the device.

Comment: I think I mean if the app is not tethered to my computer, or in other words, we didn't make the app, so we don't have the source code. We just want to track the events of the app during a specific UI scenario. What logging tools do you suggest?

Comment: You probably don't have access to that. Most apps you have access to are Distribution signed, meaning you can't get things like debugger data.

Comment: You can't use the debugger. But you can use an application (comes with Xcode) called Instruments to look at some internals of an app, even if you don't have source code.

Comment: But not log data - you mostly see allocation, and if it is distribution signed I think its a hassle to do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905450/cant-launch-my-app-in-instruments-at-least-one-target-failed-to-launch