# What means "The app must be signed with a development identity" ?

Tags: selenium, appium

What means "The app must be signed with a development identity" ?
but ipa it 's already signed from xcode...

Appium is 1.4.8

log:

```
[INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.. was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode doesn't allow you to build with a distribution certificate.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258211/4758940), you should Edit the scheme for your target and under "Profile [App Name]" set the Build Configuration to Debug (it's usually Release by default).

Comment: But what should I do if bug can be reproduced only in Release build?